# HTML CSS Apply CSS conditionally

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Hi I'm stuck at one place tried various things but not working..

I have two HTML divs

```
<div class="lmn-tab-item"></div>
<div class="lmn-tab-item lmn-tab-item-active active"></div>
```

Is there a way to apply css to lmn-tab-item if div also has class lmn-tab-item-active.
So basically I want to apply say default for first div as `color:red` and for second div if it as lmn-tab-item-active apply `color:green`

I tried below way

```
div[class^="lmn-tab-item-active"][class*=" "]:before {
  color: green!important;
}

.lmn-tab-item {
  color: red!important;
}
```

Not working, please help on this

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not 100% clear, but you can use this kind of selector:

```
.lmn-tab-item.lmn-tab-item-active {
   [your css settings]
}
```

It will only apply if an element has *both* of these classes. (note: no space between them!)

You can also do the same with three or more classes.